# Does $(AB)^m = I_n$ imply $(BA)^m = I_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

The problem is to prove or disprove that $(AB)^m = I_n$ imply $(BA)^m = I_n$ where $A, B \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I know that it's true for $m = 1$, and I tried to use the induction on $m$, but could not prove the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For negative $m$, note that $(AB)^m=I$ implies $[(AB)^m]^{-1}=(AB)^{-m}=I$.

Since $A,B$ are invertible, we get $B\underbrace{(AB)(AB)...(AB)}_{|m|\text{ times}}B^{-1}=BIB^{-1}=I$ and using the associativity of matrix multiplication we get $(BA)^{|m|}=I$.

For negative $m$, this implies $(BA)^{-|m|}=(BA)^m=I$.

Comment: Could you comment on the invertibility? Are you are taking determinants to check it or what ?

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, you can take determinants. Or we can note that $\ker(B)\subseteq\ker(AB)\subseteq\ker((AB)^m)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Perfect thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From $(AB)^m=I_n$, one obtain $A^{-1}=B(AB)^{m-1}$.

Hence $(BA)^m=B(AB)^{m-1}A=I_n$.